# How to solve this error: Unexpected error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles'

Tags: permissions

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. When conduction a host-check the following error message appears:

> ERROR -- Linux Security Modules
> Unexpected error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles'

I have changed permissions of this file `/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles`, and now the permissions are the following:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  7 14:37 profiles
```

But it does not help. Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't do anything with the `sys` directory - it's a dir managed by the kernel.

Comment: I am going to install a new application, to check whether the system settings support the application I ran ./host-check -p xrd-vrouter -e docker -e xr-compose

Comment: This is the part of the script host-check that imho leads to the error message:

def _apparmor_is_enabled() -> bool:
    """True if AppArmor is enabled."""
    try:
        with open(
            "/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles", encoding="utf-8"
        ) as f:
            contents = f.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # If the file is not found apparmor is not installed.
        return False

    # If the file is not empty apparmor is running.
    return contents != ""

Comment: I can open /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles with sudo. The script does not use sudo, as my application probably later either. Question is: how can I make the file readable w/o using sudo rights?

Comment: chown does not work ->  Operation not permitted

Comment: It seems to me you're doing something you shouldn't be doing, but I don't understand the problem. Seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: I suppose sys dir can't be changed as already stated by Artur with just userspace tools.

Comment: Maybe start by (in your question) to explain what `./host-check` is, because it's not a default Ubuntu script afaik.

Comment: yeah Artur, your are most probably right (-; Many thanks for your feedback here.

Comment: host-check is a helper tool to check the host is set up correctly for running XRd containers. Can be found here: https://github.com/ios-xr/xrd-tools/tree/main/scripts. When executing this script, the error message of the permission of file /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles appears. I need to get this fixed upfront deploying my container.

Comment: Mm-hmm. I would assume `host-check` has to be run as root.

Comment: yeah, when running the host-check as root it works. But I fear that the container I would like to deploy would access the file in the same manner as the script does.

Comment: here you can find the documentation for this host-check script, please look at chapter 'Running the host-check script': https://xrdocs.io/virtual-routing/tutorials/2022-08-22-setting-up-host-environment-to-run-xrd/

Answer (score 1):

Scripts that need to access kernel resources (like `/sys/kernel`) will have to run as `root`.

Comment: Thanks Artur for this clear statement. I will feedback this to the owner of the page I shared. Probably it is wrong documented there. Many thanks for your support, very much appreciated.